# Styling moving when viewed from phone

Tags: html, css

My code works fine on pc, but there is a white space when I view this code from a mobile. Is there a simple way to fix this?

[PC VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYYET.png) I [PHONE VIEW (iphone X)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTTTF.png)

edit: so yeah, the stuff thats moving is inline so it doesent take up the whole width, thats why its probably moving, How do I turn them that they have the width of the whole page (i assume that would fix it).

this is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>Matej Krajcovic portfolio</title>
   <!-- body one -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- heading -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&family=Montserrat:ital@1&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- skuska -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&family=Tangerine:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
 
 
<body class="clear_margin">
 
<div class="clear_margin addpadding">
 
    <img class="top-cloud"src="cloud.png" alt="a cloud image">
    <h1 class="h1element">I'm Matej Krajčovič</h1>
    <p style="font-size:1.375em;"><strong>hi stackoverflowr</strong></p>
    <img class="bottom-cloud"src="cloud.png" alt="a cloud image">
    <img src="mountain.png" alt="a mountain image">
 
 
</div>
 
<!-- IMPORTED PART -->
 
<div class="middle-container">
    <div class="profile">
      <img class="profile-photo" src="download.png" alt="an image of me">
      <h2>Hello.</h2>
      <p>Im a high-school student graduating in 2024.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
 
 
    <div class="skills">
      <h2>My Skills.</h2>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <img style="height: 10em;" class="" src="code.png" alt="a pic of a prog. reference">
 
        <ul class="no-bullets" style="position: relative;right: 2.375em;">
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title">HTML</span>
                <span class="star">★★★☆☆</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title" style="position: relative;right: 0.625em;">CSS</span>
                <span class="star">★☆☆☆☆</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title" style="position: relative;left:0.25em;">Python</span>
                <span class="star">★★★☆☆</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title"style="position:relative;right:0.5em;">Java</span>
                <span class="star">★★☆☆☆</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title"style="position:relative;left:0.3125em;">Arduino</span>
                <span class="star">★★☆☆☆</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title"style="position:relative;left:0.875em;">JavaScript</span>
                <span class="star">★☆☆☆☆</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
 
      </div>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <img class="" src="" alt="">
        <h3 style="font-size: 1.6875em;">Other skills</h3>
        <p>English (B2)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
 
    <div class="contact-me">
      <h2 style="font-size: 1.6875em;">Get In Touch</h2>
 
      <p>Contact me if you're interested, I offer freelance work in order to get some experience</p>     
      <a class="btn inter-link" href="mailto:mymail">CONTACT ME</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 
 
  <div class="bottom-container">
    <a class="footer-link inter-link" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/sudolake">Github‏‏‎ ‎</a>
    <a class="footer-link inter-link" target="_blank"  href="https://sudolake.github.io/CV/">‏‏‎ ‎Website</a>
    <p>© 2021 Matej Krajčovič</p>
  </div>
 
</body>
</html>
 
 
 
 
 
 <!-- CSS CODE -->
 <!-- CSS CODE -->
<!-- CSS CODE -->
 
.clear_margin{margin: 0 0 0 0;
              margin-top: 0;
              margin-block-start: 0;
              margin-block-end: 0;
 
            }
.h1element{margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    font-size: 4.6875em;
}
 
body{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;}
 
 
h2{font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;}  
h3{font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;}    
.profile-photo{
 
    height: 180px;
 
}
 
 
.addpadding{
    background-color: #EAF6F6;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 11.25em;}
 
.top-cloud{
    position: absolute;
    right: 23.75em;
    top: 5em;
    display: inline-block;
 
}
.bottom-cloud{
    position: absolute;
    left: 20.625em;
    top: 21.875em;
 
 
}
 
.no-bullets{    
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    margin-right: 0.8em;
}
 
.ability-title{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 17em;
}
.star{font-size:1.5em;}
 
 
 
.inter-link:hover{color: red;}  
.inter-link{color: darkblue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the @media tag

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Just troubleshoot with your phone and see what works best for you

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out for you here on codepen: https://codepen.io/ifycode/pen/gOwyryE so that you can experiment with the code there too.

In the html, remove the inline styles for the no-bullets class and the ability-title class like so:

```
<ul class="no-bullets">
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title">HTML</span>
                <span class="star">★★★☆☆</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title">CSS</span>
                <span class="star">★☆☆☆☆</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title">Python</span>
                <span class="star">★★★☆☆</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title">Java</span>
                <span class="star">★★☆☆☆</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title">Arduino</span>
                <span class="star">★★☆☆☆</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ability-title">JavaScript</span>
                <span class="star">★☆☆☆☆</span>
            </li>
      </ul>
```

In the css style make changes to these blocks:

```
.no-bullets{    
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
   /* margin-right: 0.8em;*/
}

.no-bullets > li{ /**/
   /* border: 1px solid blue;*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center
}
 
.ability-title{
   /* border: 1px solid red;*/
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6.25em; 
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
.star{
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
}
```

With this, you don't need a media query for it to cooperate on smaller devices (except if you want something in the style to be different for both laptop and phone).

I added borders so you can visualize what I did. I commented out the borders in the code, but here is how it looks like when you remove the comments. This is my iphone X phone emulator in my dev tool:

[image]

**Code explanation:**

- I removed the inline styles for the no-bullets class and the ability-title class, and also margin-right from . no-bullets so that I can have a fresh new start.
- Turned both children of li element to inline block.
- Reduced the width of .ability-title as 17em is veeeeeeery wide. You can use this converter to experiment by converting 17em to px: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_pxtoemconversion.asp
- Also aligned the texts in .ability-title to the left so that they can all look like they start at/from same point.
- Applied display flex to the li element which will enable me to use the margin auto approach on its children elements.
- Here's how the margin auto works for the children:
  The .ability-title elements get margin-left auto which shifts them towards the right.
  The .star elements get margin-right auto which shifts them towards the left.
  (That is why both of them are able to stay in the middle that way). You can also achieve this in some other approach.

Don't worry, as you continue to grow you will continue to get acquainted with proper use of position relative, right, left, margins etc.

One more thing. Try not to use inline styles as it's harder to read the code and not easy to debug.

That's it. I hope this helps!